# FileHelpers, how to separate text in multiple classes using only one line , identified by keys?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a text that is more or less like this:

> I10JOAO OF SILVAI202210I30 ...

where :
I10 is a key to the Person class
I20 is a key to another class
so on ...

How to proceed using the FileHelpers library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest that you pre-parse the file into a temporarily file containing multiple lines which have the |10, |20, |xx prefix then use the record selection techniques described in the [Avanced - Multi Record Selection](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine).

Comment: The problem is that the file has only one line, and this line I identify the record by a key.

example:


Where the record "I10000" after it I have:

        [FieldFixedLength (4)]
         public string TipoRegistro;

         [FieldFixedLength (2)]
         public string subtype;
        
         [FieldFixedLength (70)]
         [FieldTrim (TrimMode.Both)]
         public string Name;
`code`
         [FieldFixedLength (8)]
         [FieldConverter (ConverterKind.Date, "DDMMYYYY")]
         public DateTime DataConfirmacao;

Comment: This is why I'm saying pre-parse it to split out by the key values. Then import with File Helpers.

Comment: Example:
I10000GHERSON DYWYNO ESPHYNDOLA                                             2902198062903201200                    I10100MOME MAE                                                                                                     A900002024                                NADA CONSTA PARA O CPF CONSULTADO

Comment: I could make a change in FileHelpers and implement the research?

[FixedLengthRecord (FixedMode.AllowMoreChars, "I10000")]
     public class X {
}

Comment: Ok your example gives one line but how you do you expect that broken up ? What signifies the next record ?

Comment: I10000 class X { properties... }
I10100 class X2 { properties... }
A90000 class X3 { properties... }

Comment: Then yes, do what is suggested and write some code to pass over the file to separate out each line by splitting the single one. Then with the new output use filehelpers multi record options. It will be far easier in the long run.